# Can I disable or hide Windows 10 Quick Actions?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Windows 10 "Quick Actions" are probably quite helpful when you're on a tablet, but for a desktop PC the majority of them are useless:

[image]

Given than I'm unable to configure them to things which would be more useful on a desktop PC, how can I turn them off or hide them?

(The best I'm able to do is collapse them to a row of 4, but I'd like to go further)

Comment: Does disabling the complete Action Center meet your needs? [How to Enable or Disable the Action Center in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6004-action-center-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html). If so, please let me know and I will write it up as an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid not as I actually like the Action Center, just not the limited selection of Quick Actions!

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try ;)